# Correct tag for Windows Phone 8

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

Just noticed that the tag [windowsphone8](/questions/tagged/windowsphone8) has been created.

My understanding of the tag naming conventions was that hyphens were preferred, so the tag should be [windows-phone-8](/questions/tagged/windows-phone-8) which would also be in line with the existing [windows-phone-7](/questions/tagged/windows-phone-7) tag.

I tried to make the change myself since there are only two questions so far with the tag but when I tried to save the edit got an orange warning box stating that:

```
You are attempting to create the tag windows-phone-8 ; however the tag windowsphone8 already exists
```

I'm guessing this is to prevent duplicate tags being created, but in this case seems to be a false positive.

Presuming I was right in the correct name:

- Can users with edit rights work around this?
- If no, can a mod please tidy up the tag?

Comment: I can't believe that tag was made by a user with 36k rep... you'd think he'd at least try to be consistent with the hyphenation that is so obvious and widely-used already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed that.  The tag is [windows-phone-8](/questions/tagged/windows-phone-8).

Comment: Am I right that [windowsphone8] should be added as a synonym of the correct tag too? If I am, is it helpful to ask questions here on meta about required synonyms? I tried to create it myself but don't have (and I may never have!) the rep in that tag. Several other tags could do with similar synonym mapping too.

Comment: @DavidHall We could, but considering there are only six questions at the time of this post, it would be a bit premature, IMO.  That said, if people start adding it, then we can make it a synonym, and the autocomplete should help tremendously with getting them to use the hyphenated version.

Comment: @DavidHall If there are *other* tags where this schism already exists, then yes, we should create synonyms.  You can promote them [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128315/140951) or create a new meta topic for them.