# Combine tags on Windows Phone?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request

Recently I have found that there are too many of Windows Phone tags which is quite confusing when doing some search.

As you can see, currently we have 6 tags talking about Windows Phone.

[windows-phone](/questions/tagged/windows-phone)

[windows-phone-7](/questions/tagged/windows-phone-7)

[windows-phone-7.1](/questions/tagged/windows-phone-7.1)

[windows-phone-7.1.1](/questions/tagged/windows-phone-7.1.1)

[windows-phone-7.5](/questions/tagged/windows-phone-7.5)

[windows-phone-8](/questions/tagged/windows-phone-8)

I know there are already some topics discussing about the windows phone duplicate tags:

[Tags [windows-phone-7.1] and [windows-phone-mango] are synonymous](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96033/tags-windows-phone-7-1-and-windows-phone-mango-are-synonymous)

[Change [windows-phone-7] to [windows-phone]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100602/change-windows-phone-7-to-windows-phone)

[Correct tag for Windows Phone 8](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136992/correct-tag-for-windows-phone-8)

But I still think we should combine them, because sometimes for the asker, they've no idea what tags they should add, so they may just put the tags randomly or just put windows-phone on it, that makes people search question harder.

Comment: Windows Phone 7 is not Windows Phone 7.5 is not Windows Phone 7.8 is not Windows Phone 8. It doesn't make sense to combine them because they are all different incarnations of Windows Phone.

Comment: The main problem I see currently is that the synonyms that exist are kind of messed up. windows-phone-7.5 should be a synonym of windows-phone-7.1 (as they are the same thing) not one of windows-phone-7.

Comment: @Ral Zarek: Yeah, that should be sorted out. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129607/tag-windows-phone-7-5-should-be-a-synonym-for-windows-phone-7-1-not-windows

Comment: I believe there's another problem with Windows Phone, related to how general/version-specific tags work. Say you have a question on C#, users will naturally tag them 'C#' and will use version-specific only if appropriate. With WP, the problem is that 'Windows Phone 7' is a brand as much as a version. So users tend to use that tag, and only a few questions are tagged 'Windows Phone'. At first it was fine, but now you have to follow the tags 'Windows Phone', 'Windows Phone 7', 'Windows Phone 7.1', 'Windows Phone 7.1.1', and 'Windows Phone 8' to get all WP-related questions. What a pain.

Comment: For the love of christ COMBINE THEM PLEASE!!! People are abusing the tags just to get views on their questions. Go look at how many questions people post that SPECIFICALLY say windows 8 in the title and then tag all the windows 7.X tags. This is RIDICULOUS Just combine them into Windows Phone 7.X And Windows Phone 8.X

Comment: I have re-hashed this argument once again here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225888/windows-phone-tags-need-to-be-cleaned-up please come and show support so we can finally get this done.

Answer (score 3):

There is currently tag [windows-phone-7](/questions/tagged/windows-phone-7) with synonyms [wp7](/questions/tagged/wp7) and [windows-phone-7.5](/questions/tagged/windows-phone-7.5).
There is also another tag [windows-phone-7.1](/questions/tagged/windows-phone-7.1) with synonym [windows-phone-mango](/questions/tagged/windows-phone-mango).
Obviously these tags are wrongly matched. These five should be in my opinion all merged into one tag [windows-phone-7](/questions/tagged/windows-phone-7).
There is currently no point now for distinguishing between WP7 and WP7.5, because developers can now target only WP7.5, no longer WP7.

Note there is also new tag [windows-phone-8](/questions/tagged/windows-phone-8), that should be kept separate.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that we are seeing is that there are all these tags but people aren't following all of them equally.

So someone will post a question that targets windows phone 8 but then they use ALL of the windows phone tags like this guy here [windows phone 8 binding list inside list to the listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19604740/windows-phone-8-binding-list-inside-list-to-the-listbox)

I suggest we just combine all of the windows phone tags into 2 tags. Windows-Phone7.X and Windows-Phone8.X

Please, for the sake of my sanity, stop the madness and combine these.

Answer (score 0):

I think all mentioned tags should be merged to [windows-phone](/questions/tagged/windows-phone).

Sure, there are significant differences between the versions. But do we realy need that distinction?

Most questions posted these days address developing for WP 8. But the question could be relevant for earlier versions as well. If the poster is unaware of that, he'll probably tag it with WP 8 where WP would be a better tag. The community could correct this but why would we lay this burden upon the community?

Suppose the tags are merged and a developer has a question related to a specific version. He can only pick WP so the tagging system obscures that it his question is related to a specific version. Is this bad? I don't think so. The question and the answers can address the fact that it relates to a specific version.

Pros:

- Clean tags
- Just one tag to follow when you are intereseted in Windows
  Phone development
- Easy to use for new and seasoned developers
- Future proof (more or less)

Cons:

- Loose specifics

By the way, our highly fragmented and frequent updated friends from [android](/questions/tagged/android) use just one tag. I'm not sure if that should be considered a pro or a con... B-)