# Windows-Phone tags need to be cleaned up

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms, mobile-web

Windows-Phone tags need to be cleaned up

Currently we have a number of Windows Phone tag variations and it just muddies the water.

I don't see why we need

Windows-Phone 7   (Deprecated platform)

Windows-Phone 7.1 (Deprecated Platform)

Windows-Phone 7.8 (Soon to be deprecated)

Windows-Phone 8

Windows-Phone 8.1 (Releasing this quarter)

AND a Windows-Phone tag

We need to go one way or the other with this.

Either itemize every single platform variation like we have been and drop the general tag or have a couple general tags like Windows-Phone 7.x and Windows-Phone 8.x instead of 1000 other tags.

People are just abusing the system.

Today I edited a question that had Windows Store and Windows Phone tagged even though it clearly was for windows store for the tablet.

Windows Phone developers are projected to double in number in 2014. Can we please get out ahead of this and clean up this garbage?

### Edit:

For those of you that think this is a rediculous request, please look at all of the devs on Meta asking for this. If you don't work on this device then you have no clue obviously that this is a problem. The people that DO work on this device are attempting to get the communities attention to fix this problem.

Here is another post about this problem that was OVERWHELMINGLY supported.

[Combine tags on Windows Phone?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153661/combine-tags-on-windows-phone/)

The OP Also lists a number of other discussions on the topic.
This is something that needs to get done. Lets stop standing in the way of progress.

Comment: Just because a platform has been deprecated, that doesn't make all the **historical** questions about it invalid.  When it's time, tag synonyms can take care of the problem.  Is it really time to merge **all** of those tags?  I can see the argument for 7, but for 8?

Comment: If you can see the argument for 7 then why not get it done? Why not support this effort? It seems like everyone wants to stand in the way of progress because everyone wants to play devils advocate. Lets use common sense here. What possible good could come from keeping the 7, 7.1 and very soon the 7.8 tags? What historical service is that providing? Because one day 5 years from now some lonely middle aged hairy man in his mothers basement might want to relive the Windows Phone 7 days and needs a reference? Common....

Comment: @Charles Are you even qualified to speak on this topic? Have you worked with the Windows Phone? Are you familiar with the differences in the tags? Do you understand why they are no longer relevant and should be removed?

Comment: I work with Windows Phone and wouldn't want to see all the tags smushed together. If you think people are mistagging then retag. But one giant tag with a collection of both relevant and obsolete stuff in there together? No way.

Comment: @KateGregory I am not suggesting we do that. I am suggesting we do a 7.X tag and an 8.X tag or at VERY LEAST remove the deprecated tags. It is just throwing mud in the water for a platform that is already under documented in comparison to the others

Comment: First, your question isn't clear about what you're suggesting at all, and second, removing the deprecated tags is a bad idea. Keep the obsolete questions away from the mainstream by tagging with them.

Comment: @AMR Why would we remove the tags which have been deprecated. They show that the question is about a deprecated version, and which one

Comment: @RichardTingle We would remove them because you can't deploy windows phone 7 apps anymore. You can't send the to the market. You can't build for them. Why keep a tag that is utterly useless? It serves zero purpose. No one in the future can benefit from such a tag.

Comment: @AMR That seems like an argument for removing the questions, removing the tag would create a disaster. I don't know enough about the windows platform to comment to strongly, but you usually find some old models kicking around doing strange things

Comment: I don't understand why there is such a force in the way of this when so many people have voiced their concern about this issue. I could understand if I were the only person out on a limb but this has come up multiple times over the past year.

Comment: @AMR Ok, let me set out a scenario here: "Question: How do I `foo()` my `baa()`? [Windows Phone, Windows Phone-7] "Answer: "you `baz`". Windows Phone 8 developer finds question: "O this doesn't apply to windows phone 8, fine, *leaves*. **Now** [Windows Phone-7] is unceremoniously removed.  "Question: How do I `foo()` my `baa()`? [Windows Phone] "Answer: "you `baz`". Windows Phone 8 developer finds question, tries to `baz`, gets angry, **wastes entire day**

Comment: I acknowledge your very valid test case. However if that is the case then we should change the tags to have a (Deprecated) identifier in them. Attempting to defend that we keep them as is, is like ignoring that you have a gushing wound. There is an obvious problem, we need a solution. Its only going to get worse from here if we dont develop one and this has been identified a number of times as a problem.

Comment: @AMR I didn't know you can't create WP7 apps anymore (I don't do phone dev). I can't find a source for this though, could you point me to one?

Comment: Of course the real problem is developers who ride roughshod over any concept of backwards compatibility

Comment: @Stijn I don't know of a specific source however I can tell you that when you submit your XAP file to the market its version is verified. Only deployments of 7.8 and 8 are currently allowed through the gates. I will look through the documentation and see if I can find this.

Comment: @AMR Is windows phone fully closed? Or can you install apps through other platforms like with android? And if you include "rooting" then the skys the limit

Comment: @RichardTingle yes Windows phone is, for all intents and purposes, closed to third party app stores. I have heard rumors that consumers can now deploy a limited number of uncertified apps to their phone but I think this has to be done through the beta testing tools that utilize the windows phone market deployment backbone at create.msdn.com Once again, I don't know for sure. Ive never had a windows phone that wasn't developer unlocked so Ive never encountered this test case

Comment: @AMR, one does not need to be a subject matter expert to know good and bad tagging on SO.  It happens that I'm a *tagging* subject matter expert.  :p  The same goes for closing questions, doing edit reviews, and other tasks.

Comment: "one does not need to be a subject matter expert to know good and bad tagging on SO" I wholeheartedly believe that is why we have this problem in the first place. If you aren't aware of the variations in tag meanings, or have never worked in the language for that matter, then how can you claim to know right from wrong.

Answer (score 6):

### Removing deprecated tags

This would be a disaster, simply removing or merging these tags would remove all information about the fact that the answers will all refer to a deprecated version. I would like to show this through a short play

> > **Setting:**
> > "Question: How do I `foo()` my `baa()`?
> > [Windows Phone, Windows Phone-7]
> > "Answer: "you `baz`".
> > Windows Phone 8 developer finds question
>
> Windows Phone 8 developer: O this doesn't apply to windows phone 8, fine,
>
> *Windows Phone 8 developer exit stage left*.
>
> *A day passes, the [Windows Phone-7] tag is removed because it applies onto to a deprecated version*
>
> > **Setting:**
> > "Question: How do I `foo()` my `baa()`?
> > [Windows Phone]
> > "Answer: "you `baz`".
> > Another Windows Phone 8 developer finds question
>
> Another Windows Phone 8 developer: Excellent, this is exactly what I need, and highly upvored too!
>
> *developer spends the next several hours attempting to use `baz` to solve their problems, but it just refuses to work. developer has been set back by a day and is very annoyed with stack overflow*

So in other words a tag for a deprecated version is still valuable

### Old questions to deprecated versions should be deleted

This argument has more plausibility to it. **But** you will always find someone struggling on with an old version of something (perhaps a windows-phone-7 phone is driving a robot somewhere and needs custom software written for it - have actually seen this, although it may have been an android phone). Deleting these questions seems counterproductive unless literally zero people will need them again.

Comment: Questions for deprecated versions can still be helpful in solving issues in current versions if the related features did not change between versions.